# Resolving Google Play Store Crashes

Tags: android, google-play, phonegap-build

I have developed my android application using Phonegap platform and deployed into Google Play store. It works fine but there were few crash reposts

[image: Crash report - Screenshot]

Is there any way to resolve this issues? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is summary of runtime crashes so please update your code and retest it on specific device on which it has been crashed and upload new apk. This is the only solution.